# htaccess symfony mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

How can I setup an htaccess to handle my url like following:

```
http://domain.tld/app.php/
http://domain.tld/app.php/link1
http://domain.tld/app.php/link1/link2
```

and it should look like:

```
http://domain.tld/link1/link2
```

I'm stucking using the right htaccess rules. Do I have to handle each "folder" as an parameter?

Comment: The .htaccess that comes with the Symfony Standard Edition should be already doing what you need. Have you modified it in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like that :

```
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) /$2 [R=301,L]
```

On a side note, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

> Ps : no, you don't have to handle each folder as a parameter. And don't put app.php in your url anyway, you don't need it, so you shouldn't have app.php/* urls in your site and you shouldn't need this redirect *anyway*

Comment: thank you all, I will check it and get back with a solution. maxbe I'm just miss anything. I use the origin htaccess as it is delivered from symfony

Comment: so, It is a bit weird. If i use http://domain.tld/app.php it will be rewritten to http://domain.tld and it works. after sending a form, which has the the same route I get an 500 error without any entry in the error.log :(

Comment: I guess this has nothing to do with your Apache rules. Check your PHP  logs for instance